# MySQL - Find all locations near a list of locations. E.g. all houses near any park. Subquery?

Tags: mysql, location, subquery

I have 2 tables one with a list of 150 locations for type A (lets call them parks) and one with a list of (several 1000) locations for type B (lets say houses).

What I want to do is find **all** the houses within 1 mile of **any** park(s) and list those parks.

I can do this using a nested query and it isn't too slow but I figured there is a more elegant solution. I never really use subqueries so if this is the way to go some help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with a simple cross join between the tables, but you need to calculate the distance (simple enough - plenty of examples if you google for them).

Only issue is performance, as you will be doing potentiall 150,000 distance calculations for each time you do the query.

Comment: You're right here's what I used. Pretty crude but gives a rough (as the crow flies) distance:
SELECT a.name, b.name, (ABS(a.lat-b.lat) + ABS(a.lon-b.lon))*64 AS dist 
FROM `houses` a, parks b
WHERE ( (ABS(a.lat-b.lat) + ABS(a.lon-b.lon))*64) < 1